# How to read .xlsx and .xls files using C# and OleDbConnection?

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

Previously I was using `ExcelPackage` to read data out of a .xlsx file. That was working fine but then I realized that `ExcelPackage` doesn't work with the old .xls format. So I upgraded to using `OleDbConnection` instead of `ExcelPackage` like this:

```
var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
DataTable sheetData = new DataTable();
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
    file.FileName + "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;\"";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    DataTable dtSchema = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
    string sheetName = dtSchema.Rows[0].Field("TABLE_NAME");
    OleDbDataAdapter sheetAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [" + sheetName + "]", conn);
    sheetAdapter.Fill(sheetData);
}
```

Basically just trying to read the first spreadsheet there. But I get this error in the exception:

`Cannot update.  Database or object is read-only.`

What am I doing wrong? Is there some type of update operation hidden in there?

Comment: Try to close the excel file you are reading in C#

Comment: Do you have Excel open, and by chance this particular file?

Comment: I don't have the file open in excel. Christian, what do you mean close the file? Samething as mad?

Comment: Where is the excel file located? Is it local? I get error with the posted code, however, There must be something else going on. The error `Cannot update` seems like an odd error if you are simply trying to READ the file.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
OleDbConnection connection;
OleDbCommand command;
OleDbDataReader dr;

        string commandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";
        string oledbConnectString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
        @"Data Source=" + filename + ";" +
        "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES\";";
        connection = new OleDbConnection(oledbConnectString);
        command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                count++;

                for (int i = 1; i < dr.VisibleFieldCount; i++)
                {
                   Console.Writeln(""+dr[i].ToString());
                }
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex.Message);
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: When I try that I get this: `The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.`

Comment: @Ryan so the problem is your file. Please check if it's in use or whether you have permission to edit it or not :D

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example method that returns a `DataSet` from the given excel file path. The returned `DataSet` should have each Excel worksheet in the workbook as a `DataTable` in the `DataSet`. This appears to work correctly, hope it may help.

```
private DataSet GetExcelDataSet(string path) {
  string sheetName;
  string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path +
                        "; Jet OLEDB:Engine Type = 5; Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0;\"";
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString)) {
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()) {
      using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter()) {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        for (int i = 0; i < dtExcelSchema.Rows.Count; i++) {
          sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
          DataTable dt = new DataTable(sheetName);
          cmd.Connection = con;
          cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
          oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
          oda.Fill(dt);
          dt.TableName = sheetName;
          ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return ds;
}
```